# Why initial-scale=1.0 makes the elements left aligned?

Tags: html, mobile

I have an HTML page and I want some elements to be centered. I need it to work with mobile devices, so I added

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

but I see (with Chrome mobile emulator and real iPhone 7) all the elements left aligned.

If I change initial-scale to 0.5 the elements are centered, but Google says the text is too small.

I'm centering the elements this way

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>
        <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">Example<div>
    </h1>
</div>
```

How can I have initial-scale set to 1 and the elements centered?